# Combing Streams in Scala?

Tags: scala, stream

I'm trying to combine a few Stream[String] into one, to be processed by functions downstream, not caring about orders. What's the proper way of doing this in Scala?  Collect?  foldLeft?

```
  files.map(getContentAsStream).collect(?)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reduce` and the [`++`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream@++[B%3E:A,That](that:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicitbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A],B,That]):That) function which concatenates both streams:

```
files.map(getContentAsStream).reduce(_ ++ _)
```

Comment: I was able to do this using files.map().toStream.flatten, lol